# How to check that user deleted the cookies of the webpage or has a session timeout?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using Node.js + Express with Socket.io.
My problem is, that i can't figure out how to notice when the user clears the browser history or is inactive for X minutes and his session times out. On my page when user clears browser history or is timed out, the socket connection isn't refused and user can still get notifications from other users through socket.io. I have implemented a friend list for users too, and that doesn't works too, the timeouted or "cookie deleted" user still remains online.
I need a similar method that the socket.io disconnect event, what fires when the browser window is closed:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('User disconnected');
});
```

How to get this worked? If you can't, i dont need a concrete code, a method for solving this problem is enough too. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. As of your code now, when is the `socket.on('disconnect', ...` fired?

Comment: It's in the question...when i close the browser window.